# python django iam stack in this part of code shown below .error displayed un IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, django

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your simplesite models here.

class simplesite(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    due_date=models.DateTimeField()

#simplest app model

class simplest(models.Model):
    simple_site=models.foreignkey(simplesite)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    due_date=models.DateTimeField()
```

This is the error displayed when i run this command: `python .\manage.py makemigrations simplest`

```
PS C:\django\simplesite> python .\manage.py makemigrations simplest
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
        django.setup()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "C:\django\simplesite\simplest\models.py", line 9
    due_date=models.DateTimeField()
                                  ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

any please help i am stack on that place .i am a beginner in python django framework

Answer (score -1):

This is a basic python syntax issue. Make sure you have not mixed spaces and tabs in your indentation.

Comment: ** i have checked and still displaying the same error**

Comment: 'from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your simplesite models here.

class simplesite(models.Model):
 name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    due_date=models.DateTimeField()

#simplest app model

class simplest(models.Model):
 simple_site=models.foreignkey(simplesite)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    due_date=models.DateTimeField() '

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure your editor to be 4 spaces by tab and not only tab, because four spaces for python is not the same that one tab.

You have to make sure that all the code is using four spaces the code

Comment: **how do i configure my editor.iam using pycharm2016.2.3**

Comment: There is a little [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/quick-start-guide.html#init) you can configure pycharm to show points insted of spaces and you could find the line that has the indentation problem